# How to get directory size in node.js without recursively going through directory?

Tags: node.js, fs

How do I get the size of a directory in node.js without recursively going through all the children in a directory?

E.g.

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.statSync('path/to/dir');
```

Will return me an object like this,

```
{ dev: 16777220,
  mode: 16877,
  nlink: 6,
  uid: 501,
  gid: 20,
  rdev: 0,
  blksize: 4096,
  ino: 62403939,
  size: 204,
  blocks: 0,
  atime: Mon May 25 2015 20:54:53 GMT-0400 (EDT),
  mtime: Mon May 25 2015 20:09:41 GMT-0400 (EDT),
  ctime: Mon May 25 2015 20:09:41 GMT-0400 (EDT) }
```

But the `size` property is not the size of the directory and it's children (aka the sum of the files inside of it).

Is there no way to get the size of a dir (w/the sizes of the files inside of it included) without recursively finding the sizes of the children (and then summing those up)?

I'm basically trying to do the equivalent of `du -ksh my-directory` but if the given directory is really large (e.g `/`) than it takes forever to recursively get the true dir size..

Comment: I know that `du -ksh /` takes forever so maybe this question is ... mute... I'm hoping there's a linuxy thing I'm missing here..

Comment: `du` does exactly that, so no, you can’t get around it.

Comment: As best I know, directories don't keep track of the accumulated size of all files below them so the only way to get the accumulated size is to recurse and add.  It is not a fast operation.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "without recursively going through directory"? Do you mean (A) a library function that gives you the answer with a one-line call so that *you* don't have to do the recursion yourself, or (B) an implementation of a function that walks the tree without making any recursive function calls, or (C) to get the answer without anyone (your or the function you call) iterating over the directory contents? If (C), that's impossible, as @jfriend00 points out. Even `du` internally iterates over all the files. Please clarify.

Answer (score 19):

I use this simple [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) + [fs Promises API](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_promises_api) (Node.js v14+) solution... It doesn't depend on external libraries or spawning new processes which is nice:

```js
const path = require('path');
const { readdir, stat } = require('fs/promises');

const dirSize = async directory => {
  const files = await readdir( directory );
  const stats = files.map( file => stat( path.join( directory, file ) ) );

  return ( await Promise.all( stats ) ).reduce( ( accumulator, { size } ) => accumulator + size, 0 );
}
```

Usage:

```js
( async () => {
  const size = await dirSize( '/path/to/directory' );
  console.log( size );
} )();
```

This doesn't use any *loop constructs* to recurse through the directory, although it is mapping/reducing arrays. The other solutions are just abstracting recursion behind NPM packages/C code so it should be all good...

---

*Update:* I had used the above solution for getting a directory without recursively going through child directories based on my previous use case... Also it is clear reading question again that the original poster wanted the sizes from child directories as well.

This should do the trick if anyone is looking for that; however it technically doesn't the bill of avoiding recursion. Thatnks for the comment @Inigo!

```js
const { readdir, stat } = require('fs/promises');
const { join } = require('path');

const dirSize = async dir => {
  const files = await readdir( dir, { withFileTypes: true } );

  const paths = files.map( async file => {
    const path = join( dir, file.name );

    if ( file.isDirectory() ) return await dirSize( path );

    if ( file.isFile() ) {
      const { size } = await stat( path );
      
      return size;
    }

    return 0;
  } );

  return ( await Promise.all( paths ) ).flat( Infinity ).reduce( ( i, size ) => i + size, 0 );
}
```

Usage:

```js
( async () => {
  const size = await dirSize( '/path/to/directory' );
  console.log( size );
} )();
```

Comment: Where is "path" coming from?

Comment: @bluepuma77 Hah, great question! It was undefined until I updated the answer after your your comment :P Thanks for catching that

Comment: This solution doesn't recurse through directories at all, and so will give the wrong answer if the directory has subdirectories, probably the most important use case. This earns a downvote which I'll retract if you fix it.

Comment: Ahh good catch @Inigo! I had missing the intent of the OPs question. Hopefully the addtional solution will help other postes looking for size from nested subdirectories :)

Comment: I'd get rid of your initial solution entirely. It's simply wrong, as by definition the size of a directory *must* include the size of any contained directories. As to the OP's "without recursively going through directory", see my comment under the question. If they meant (B), it's not hard to modify your solution to use a loop and a stack rather than recursion. If you've never done it, it's a good exercise to become a pro-programmer :)

Comment: "The size of a directory must include the size of any contained directories"... I would disagree with that... I replied to this thread is because I needed to build packages for a third-party application that generated a hash based purely on file sizes; I had searched for solution, this thread came up, and I decided to contribute since the solution wasn't there. Options are good; wrong problems need solutions too :) I would also argue that using a for loop to recurse infinitely through a directory is way more traditionally "recursive" than using a reducer ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: There isn't a way to do this without recursion, unless you already have a cache from recursive calls. The other answers are also recursive. but the recursive calls are in third party modules, so it doesn't make sense to exclude this answer for that.

Answer (score 8):

[fast-folder-size](https://github.com/simoneb/fast-folder-size) uses [Sysinternals DU](https://learn.microsoft.com/sysinternals/downloads/du) on Windows and the built-in `du` program on other platforms to quickly compute a folder size.

**Installation**

`npm i fast-folder-size`

**Usage**

```
const fastFolderSize = require('fast-folder-size')

fastFolderSize('.', (err, bytes) => {
  if (err) {
    throw err
  }

  console.log(bytes)
})
```

Answer (score 7):

You can either spawn a `du` command on your target directory but as you said it can be rather slow the first time. What you might not know is that `du` results seem to be cached somehow:

```
$ time du -sh /var
13G /var
du -sh /var  0.21s user 0.66s system 9% cpu 8.930 total
$ time du -sh /var
13G /var
du -sh /var  0.11s user 0.34s system 98% cpu 0.464 total
```

It took initially 8s and then only 0.4s

Hence if your directories are not changing too often, just going with `du` might be the easiest way to go.

Another solution is to store that in a cache layer, so you can watch your root directory for changes, then compute the size of the folder, store it in a cache and just serve it when needed. To perform this you could use the watch functionality of NodeJS but you'll have some cross platform issues, hence a library like chokidar might be helpful.

Comment: Even better you can get just the folder size in bytes using `du -s /var | cut -f1`

Answer (score 2):

You should try "getFolderSize" node module
https://www.npmjs.com/package/get-folder-size

Usage

```
getFolderSize(folder, [regexIgnorePattern], callback)
```

Example:

```
var getSize = require('get-folder-size');

getSize(myFolder, function(err, size) {
  if (err) { throw err; }

  console.log(size + ' bytes');
  console.log((size / 1024 / 1024).toFixed(2) + ' Mb');
});
```

Comment: Hello, please expand your answer to include a solution that is useful even without the hyperlink. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The module you post is using recursive solution. https://github.com/alessioalex/get-folder-size/blob/master/index.js#L7

Comment: may be OK for small shallow directories . Terrible for big deep directories. I'd rather run a shell command and let the OS handle it.
It also does not give the size-on-disk - which is the common motive for checking folder size.

Answer (score 0):

The following function scans the directory recursively and returns its size in bytes. May be adjusted to use `fs/promises` if you need a non-blocking approach.

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const getDirSize = (dirPath) => {
  let size = 0;
  const files = fs.readdirSync(dirPath);

  for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    const filePath = path.join(dirPath, files[i]);
    const stats = fs.statSync(filePath);

    if (stats.isFile()) {
      size += stats.size;
    } else if (stats.isDirectory()) {
      size += getDirSize(filePath);
    }
  }

  return size;
};
```